# Unable to run java files with external jar in Ubuntu

Tags: java, jar

I tried to compile my java file with an external jar in Ubuntu 14.04.

It works fine after I compile:

```
jeremy@Ubuntu:~/Desktop/project/src$ javac -classpath lib/jsch.jar MyFile.java
```

but I have the following error when I tried to run:

```
jeremy@Ubuntu:~/Desktop/project/src$ java -classpath lib/jsch.jar MyFile
Error: Could not find or load main class MyFile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the terminal run:

```
java -cp .:/path/to/jar/file MyFile
```

where you replace `/path/to/jar/file` with the full path to your external .jar file which in your question is named jsch.jar and `-cp` is a shorter way of typing `-classpath`.

#### Explanation

. - current directory
: - separator character used to separate class paths
`/path/to/jar/file` - replace this with the full path to external .jar file